# Angular.boostrap analog in Angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I need to replace the bootstrap with the angular material. For that reason I need to replace angular.boostrap with the angular material analog.
Thank you for the help in advance

```
@section jsCode {
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("customer"), ['customer']);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that, but `angular.bootstrap` means that you start an angular app. Your parameters are the modules, for instance you must have something like

```
<body ng-app="customer">
```

In your code.

If you want to use angular material along with angular, just import the library with a `script` tag (and a `link` one for the style), and add the dependency to your angular module.

To get rid of bootstrap, delete all the `script` and `link` tags that contains "bootstrap" that you have in your files.